# How to auto generate docstrings in PyCharm for dataclasses?

Tags: pycharm, auto-generate, docstring, python-dataclasses

Is there a way for auto generating docstrings for dataclasses in the same fashion of the method and function docstrings? I did not find anything useful through help / search

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class ExtractionConfig:
    """
    
    """
    gcp_bucket: str = None
    gcp_key: str = None
    log_file: str = None
    log_backup_count: int = 3
    delete_remotely: bool = True
```

When I try to manually add them, I get unresolved references:

[image: unresolved refs]

Comment: Note that @dataclass itself will already autogenerate it if one is not set: https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/pull/64

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060813/how-to-document-fields-and-properties-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125415/how-do-i-document-a-constructor-for-a-class-using-python-dataclasses

Answer (score 2):

Pycharm does not support it at this moment.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28549

Comment: In case it helps, there's a workaround, which is to add a docstring per field: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28549#focus=Comments-27-4299152.0-0