# How napoleon and autodoc interact documenting members

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, python-dataclasses, sphinx-napoleon

I noticed a change in behavior in how Sphinx renders class descriptions. Given this code

```py
# my example happens to be a dataclass, but the behavior for 
# regular classes is the same
@dataclass
class TestClass:
    """This is a test class for dataclasses.

    This is the body of the docstring description.
    """
    var_int: int
    var_str: str
```

plus some generic Sphinx settings, I used to get this about two years ago

[image: Documentation shows just the docstring]

And am now getting this

[image: Documentation shows class variables as if they were in the docstring]

Is there a way to tell Sphinx not to add the class variables to the bottom of the class definition? It's particularly annoying that it assumes their values to be `None`, just because they don't have defaults.

---

This issue came up during discussions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51131941/962190), which also contains a bit more context in comments regarding Sphinx configuration etc.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Sphinx 3.2.1 and Python 3.8.5.

Comment: When you say: *"Is there a way to tell Sphinx not to add the class variables to the bottom of the class definition?"* do you mean "not add them" at all, or include them yes but just not at the bottom? Also, what would be the desired behavior regarding the `None` value? Omit it together with the equal sign?

Comment: @bad_coder I mean not to add them at all, and the `None` behavior is just weird to me. They don't have the value None, if anything they'd be undefined. But, strictly speaking, it is a different issue.

Comment: @mzjn Got one working here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/e2de5b9ca21383e9f0606eb08a6ee50e). I tried what you suggested @bad_coder regarding `:undoc-members:`, and it solves my issue. To be honest, I never bothered to find out what the directives in autodoc-generated rst mean. Maybe the default value for `autodoc_default_options` at `undoc-members` used to be `false` and is now `true`, but I'm too lazy to hunt that info down. Feel free to post a `conf.py` that changes it back to `false` as an answer I can accept =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Members of an object are included by an autodoc directive depending if:

- the `:members:` option is used (for members with docstrings).
- the `:undoc-members:` option is used (for members without docstrings).

For example:

```
dc module
=========

.. autoclass:: dc.Foo
```

In the above `.rst` file the autodoc directive does not have explicit options set, what Sphinx will do is implicitly apply the option flags taken from the [`autodoc_default_flags`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_flags) in `conf.py`.

Setting the following in `conf.py` would cause all members of an object (with or without docstrings) to be included by Sphinx in all directives that do not explicitly specify options.

```py
# autodoc settings
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members':          True,
    'undoc-members':    True,
}
```

The result:

[image]

However, this raises a question: What do autodoc and sphinx-napoleon extensions do if members are explicitly specified in the `Attributes` [docstring section](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#id1) **but also** included by the autodoc extension?

> Docstrings
>
> [Napoleon interprets every docstring that autodoc can find (...) Inside each docstring, specially formatted Sections are **parsed and converted** to reStructuredText](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#id1).

For example, using the following docstring together with the options specified above in `autodoc_default_options`.

```py
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    """Docstring for Foo

    Attributes:
        var_a (str): An integer.
        var_b (int): A string.
    """
    var_a: str
    var_b: int
```

In this case members will be declared twice, once by each extension, with the corresponding reST declaration being generated as a duplicate. Having a duplicate reST declaration will lead to the usual warning:

> C:\dc.py:docstring of dc.Foo.var_a:1: WARNING: duplicate object description of dc.Foo.var_a, other instance in dc, use :noindex: for one of them
>
> C:\dc.py:docstring of dc.Foo.var_b:1: WARNING: duplicate object description of dc.Foo.var_b, other instance in dc, use :noindex: for one of them

Here one difference can be noted: sphinx-napoleon will declare the member in its own [docstring section](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#docstring-sections) whereas autodoc will render it normally as other members. The visual difference will depend on theme, for example using `classic` theme:

[image]

Finally, if you want to document members using sphinx-napoleon [docstring sections](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#docstring-sections) and avoid a duplicate reST declaration from autodoc while keeping `autodoc_default_options` as shown, you can explicitly use `:exclude-members:` option in that specific directive, for example:

```
dc module
=========

.. autoclass:: dc.Foo
    :exclude-members: var_a, var_b
```

Would document the members using only sphinx-napoleon generated reST directives:

[image]

Comment: Can I somehow configure the exclude-members in `conf.py`, or do I need to update the .rst every time I run sphinx-apidoc?

Comment: @Arne I wrote a [somewhat extensive post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54148095) on the difficulties of setting the default autodoc options when using `sphinx-apidoc`.  The catch is `sphinx-apidoc` takes the default options from an environment variable, not as a command line argument...As for the rest, `:exclude-members:` can be set in `autodoc_default_flags`. The right choice is setting as default the most frequently used option, whenever you want an exception to the rule set that option directly in the `.rst` directive.