# Sphinx remove dataclass fields from autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64588821/how-napoleon-and-autodoc-interact-documenting-members) describes, autodoc will eagerly add the class variables to the documentation even if napoleon adds the fields as documentation in:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Foo():
    """Some class

    Attributes:
        a: foo
        b: bar
    """
    a: str
    b: int

    def c(self) -> int:
        """Here's a doc'd function
        """
        return 3
```

I want to explicitly tell autodoc to not document any class variables (which is also instance variables in the case of dataclasses) - I only want autodoc to show declared functions for a given class and let napoleon handle the class/instance variables **for all classes it finds**. Is this possible without `:exclude-members:` for every class (which is a huge hassle)?

I already tried:

```
autodoc_default_options = {
    'members':          True,
    'undoc-members':    False,
}
```

in my `conf.py` and this in the `.rst` file:

```
.. automodule:: some.module
    :members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Which should hide undocumented members but they still show up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change `Attributes:` to `Args:`.